# Clicking on a button fires other button which holds same event function

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular7, ionic4

I'm working on an ionic project & in my project when I click on 1 button other button also changes their values as they have same event in it. But I want opposite of that, clicking on a button should only change a particular button's value.

**HTML**

```
<table class="student_list">
  <tr><ion-item *ngFor="let record of data">
        <ion-avatar slot="start">
          <img src="assets/student.png">
        </ion-avatar>
        <ion-label class="text2">{{record.name}}&ensp;{{record.id}}
        <span class="button1"><button (click)="toggleBackgroundColor()" ion-button [style.background-color]="hexColor" class="btn">{{text}}</button></span>
        </ion-label>
      </ion-item></tr>
    </table>
```

**TS file**

```
public toggleBackgroundColor(): void {
   if(this.hexColor === '#1e90ff') { 
     this.hexColor = '#ff0000'
     this.text='A';
   } else {
    this.hexColor = '#1e90ff';
     this.text = 'P'
  }   }
```

Comment: If you are binding the same variables to 2 different buttons, any change by one button will be reflected in both. You can use different variables for different buttons

Answer (score 1):

You most probably use the same bindings for both buttons. You will have to use 2 sets of separate bindings - one for each button.

Answer (score 1):

You should put an identifier on the function call to the particular tag you are invoking the call to.

```
<button id="changeable" (click)="toggleBackgroundColor('changeable')" ion-button [style.background-color]="hexColor" class="btn">{{text}}</button>
```

And the function:

```
public toggleBackgroundColor(id): void {
      var element = document.getElementById(id);
      if(element.hexColor === '#1e90ff') { 
        element.hexColor = '#ff0000'
        element.text='A';
      } else {
        element.hexColor = '#1e90ff';
        element.text = 'P'
      }   }
```

Comment: I can mention id's but how will I be able to do so when I'm using loop statement in it?

Comment: Increment the id inside the loop and append it, something like id="clickable{{$iteration}}" or whatever the equivalent in Angular. It will be rendered as id="clickable1", id="clickable2", etc.

Answer (score 1):

You might use a parameter which will differentiate buttons one from other. For example,

```
(click)="toggleBackgroundColor(1)"
```

will be used for one button and

```
(click)="toggleBackgroundColor(2)"
```

will be used for the other.
And function then become:

```
public toggleBackgroundColor(who: number): void {
   switch(who) {
       case 1: /// I'm one button
       break;
       case 2: /// I'm another :)
       break;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your other buttons use the same `hexColor` variable. So, when you modify your `hexColor`, it updates every buttons' attribute bound on `hexColor`.

I suggest you to refactor your code to modify the DOM directly.

```
<button (click)="toggleBackgroundColor($event)" 
        ion-button 
        [style.background-color]="hexColor" 
        class="btn">{{text}}
</button>


public toggleBackgroundColor(event): void {
      let btnColor = event.srcElement.style['background-color'];
      if (btnColor === '#1e90ff') { 
        btnColor = '#ff0000';
        event.srcElement.innerHTML= 'A';
      } else {
        btnColor = '#1e90ff';
        event.srcElement.innerHTML = 'P';
      }
 }
```